# Cobertura coverage for integration tests in Maven

Tags: integration-testing, maven-3, cobertura

I can invoke `mvn cobertura:cobertura` to instrument, run unit tests (using `surefire`), and generate reports.

I can invoke `mvn verify` to run unit tests and integration tests (using the `failsafe` Maven plugin).

But how do I call Maven to instrument, run unit tests and integration tests, and generate reports? The answer to [Running integration tests with Cobertura Maven plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188192/running-integration-tests-with-cobertura-maven-plugin) did not work for me, and also I would not want to call `verify` with every Cobertura run, but only for nightly coverage.

Comment: See my answer on [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034913/cobertura-and-jetty][1] . I don't post it again because it is long. 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034913/cobertura-and-jetty

Comment: However, I cannot accept your answer if it is in a comment. Please add the answer ‘have a look at cobertura-it’ below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try [Jacoco](http://www.eclemma.org/jacoco/) and got on fly instrumentation with more flexible configuration for gathering of coverage and reporting

Comment: This is actually what we do now. Cobertura has issues with Java 7 and does not work with JMockit. JaCoCo does.

Comment: Jacoco does not support aggreate reports, so if you have a multi-module project you're screwed

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I fully understand the question, but I always do a `mvn site` ...